# ¿Cómo puedo vaciar la información de una base de datos sin modificar la estructura (PK,FK,CONSTRAINST) en ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

¿Cómo puedo vaciar la información de una base de datos sin modificar la estructura (PK,FK,CONSTRAINST) en ORACLE?

Algo así como el `TRUNCATE [TABLE]` pero para toda la base.

Comment: No existe una forma fácil de hacerlo, si no tuvieras ningún tipo de constraint o Foreign key, eventualmente podrías truncar todas las tablas tal como te sugirieron. Sino, una alternativa es contar con un backup de la base limpia y recuperarlo cada vez que lo necesités, el único problema en estos casos es si haces modificaciones a la estructura.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear un script para truncar todas las tablas:

```
select 'truncate table ' || table_name || ';' from user_tables
```

Simplemente ejecuta el script y listo.

Comment: Entiendo que  esto no funcionaría si el orden de truncado no es el adecuado en tablas con foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear un procedimiento almacenado para realizar esto y crear un bloque donde coloques las instrucciones de truncate para todas las tablas y se podría ejecutar desde una linea .

Saludos.